# HTML 5 Notifications

Tags: javascript, html5, push-уведомления

Здравствуйте. Есть браузерные уведомления. Как отправить это уведомление определенному пользователю(определенному браузеру)? (все пользователи разрешили показывать оповещения и у всех пользователей есть функция, которая указана ниже. Она как для примера) 
Пример, в интернет магазине пользователь не заказал товар и администратор хочет отправить ему браузерное уведомление(только ему).

```
 function notifyMe() {
    if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
    }
    else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
    }
    else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
        Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
            if (permission === "granted") {
                var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Придумал решение. Всех посадить на каналы(с помощью сокетов) и через php отправлять на определенный канал информацию о том, что нужно показать уведомление. А на js нужно запустить функцию с определенными параметрами.